# GitHub CI based on changes in pull request not commit

Tags: git, github, yaml, continuous-integration, devops

I  have two github ci files - one for client one for server. they each have the following:

```yaml
name: Client

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'client/**'

...
```

obviously 'server' where appropriate in the other variant

this is so they only run those pipelines with changes to the respective files

this works well HOWEVER, it only detects per commit not per merge request

So for example if i change files in the `server`, those tests will run. if they fail, then the next commit i only have `client` changes then only those checks will run. Moreover, if the client changes pass it will look like my PR is passing even though my server pipeline is still broken

Comment: You can switch the trigger from `push` to `pull_request`, that should roughly do what you want.

Comment: @BenjaminW. remarkable thank you - so difficult to find that for some reason I tried similar but this seems to actually do what I need.